# How does strict_append in @incremental work?

Tags: pyspark, palantir-foundry

I try to understand what is the difference between `strict_append=False` and `strict_append=True` in `@incremental` decorator.

I watched the video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R8LVvy4v7Es and tried different combinations (uploading different files, updating records, etc), but still don't understand what is a case for `strict_append=True`.

Answer (score 0):

I have never used strict_append before, so I'm answering from reading the code. You should be able to also see the code by `ctrl` + `click` on the function (or `cmd` + `click`. It contains some pydoc which says:

> **strict_append (bool, optional):** If True, the underlying foundry transaction type will be an APPEND. Note that the write operation may not overwrite any files, even auxiliary ones such as Parquet summary metadata or Hadoop SUCCESS files. Incremental writes for all Foundry formats should support this mode.

It seems it was added on version 1.312.0

This is what I see in the code base:

```
        # The mode for an incremental write is either 'append' or 'modify', according to the `strict_append` parameter
        mode = 'replace'
        if is_incremental:
            mode = 'append' if self._strict_append else 'modify'
```

Later on the `mode` is used to instantiate the type of transaction. Given the if condition above, it seems that with `strict_append` to true, you will always get an append transaction, so you won't replace or modify the current file contents.

Comment: Yes, I saw this too and I played a bit with it but couldn't see the difference. So for example, if you update the input file that was processed, it will re-run the entire dataset anyway and overwrite the data. I would like to see a scenario that I can implement and see a difference in output.

Comment: If you re-upload a file, you always invalidate the previous transactions, so it will force a re-compute, no way around it. In the video it's shown at min 4:23

Comment: You are right, I saw it. But still, it is hard to comprehend when we need to use  strict_append=True without a real example.

Comment: I guess you would use this flag if you absolutely want to make sure that you do not overwrite any files from previous transactions.